# Cassandra: how to initialize the counter column with value?

Tags: cassandra

I have to benchmark Cassandra with the Facebook Linkbench. There are two phase during the Benchmark, the load and the request phase.
in the Load Phase, Linkbench fill the cassandra tables : nodes, links and counts (for links counting) with default values(graph data).

the count table looks like this:

`keyspace.counttable (
    link_id bigint,
    link_type bigint,
    time bigint,
    version bigint,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (link_id, link_type, time, version)`

my question is how to insert the default counter values (before incrementing and decrementing the counter in the Linkbench request phase) ?

If it isn't possible to do that with cassandra, how should i increment/decrement a bigint variable (instead of counter variable)

Any suggest and comments? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is zero. Given

`create table counttable (
    link_id bigint,
    link_type bigint,
    time bigint,
    version bigint,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (link_id, link_type, time, version)
);`

and

`update counttable set count = count + 1 where link_id = 1 and link_type = 1 and time = 1 and version = 1;`

We see that the value of count is now 1.

`select * from counttable ;
 link_id | link_type | time | version | count
---------+-----------+------+---------+-------
       1 |         1 |    1 |       1 |     1
(1 rows)`

So, if we want to set it to some other value we can:

`update counttable set count = count + 500 where link_id = 1 and link_type = 1 and time = 1 and version = 2;
select * from counttable ;
 link_id | link_type | time | version | count
---------+-----------+------+---------+-------
       1 |         1 |    1 |       1 |     1
       1 |         1 |    1 |       2 |   500
(2 rows)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way to initialize a counter column with a non-zero value. The only operation you can do on a counter field is increment/decrement. I recommend to keep the offset (e.g. the your intended initial value) in a different column, and simply add the two values in your client application.

Comment: Thank You ! im looking for a solution with only one operation and one column (increment or decrement). It must be with a counter field or an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Answers. I implemented the following solution to initialize the counter Field.
as the initial and default value of the counter Field is 0 ,i incremented it with my default value. it looks like Don Branson solution but with only one column:

create table counttable (
    link_id bigint,
    link_type bigint,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (link_id, link_type)
);

i set the value with this statement (during the load phase):

```
update counttable set count = count + myValue where link_id = 1 and link_type = 1;

select * from counttable ;

 link_id | link_type | count
---------+-----------+--------
       1 |         1 |  myValue (added to 0)

(1 row)
```